# Send notification every x seconds

Tags: java, android, service, notifications, timertask

I'm doing an app that checks the live scores. I don't know if it's the best way, but I created a Timertask, a Service and and Activity to notify.

The Timertask checks every x seconds if the score changes and if it changes, informs the Service.
If the Service is informed, it calls the Activity that will notify the user. My problem is I failed at calling the activity to Notify from the Service.

Here is my code (For the example, I didn't take the score but a variable i.

```
   //import ...

public class MyService extends Service{

    Notif notif = new Notif();

    private static final String TAG = "MyService";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Congrats! MyService Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
        Timer time = new Timer(); // Instantiate Timer Object
        final ScheduleTask st = new ScheduleTask(); // Instantiate SheduledTask class
        time.schedule(st, 0, 5000); // Create Repetitively task for every 1 secs
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyService Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    }

    public void checkI(int i){
        if (i==3){
            notif.initializeUIElements();
        }
    }
}
```

TimerTask

```
import ...

// Create a class extends with TimerTask
public class ScheduleTask extends TimerTask {
    MyService myService = new MyService();
    Notif notif = new Notif();
    int i = 0;
    // Add your task here
    public void run() {
        i++;
        System.out.println("affichage numero " + i );
        myService.checkI(i);
    }

    public int getI() {
        return i;
    }
}
```

Notif

```
import ...

public class Notif extends Activity {

    private static final int NOTIFY_ME_ID = 1987;
    private NotificationManager mgr = null;
    ScheduleTask scheduleTask = new ScheduleTask();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }

    void initializeUIElements() {
        Notification note = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                "Welcome to MyDoople.com", System.currentTimeMillis());
        PendingIntent i = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(
                this, MainActivity.class), Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT);

        note.setLatestEventInfo(this, "MyDoople.com", "An Android Portal for Development",
                i);
        // note.number = ++count;
        note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

        mgr.notify(NOTIFY_ME_ID, note);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Services may be terminated by the system if resources are needed. For your requirement, it's best to use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to periodically do something.

Here are more references: [[1]](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html#scheduleservice_scheduling), [[2]](http://code4reference.com/2012/07/tutorial-on-android-alarmmanager/)